# Setting Unselected Items in a JList table to setEnable(false)

Tags: java, jlist

I'm having difficulty changing unselected options in a `JList` table to set them to `setEnable(false)`.  The method that is receiving the values is an `ActionListener` button method that, once pressed, receives the selected values from the `JList`.  Here is the method and the `buildEnemySelectionPanel()` method is creating the `JList` with the appropriate `JPanel` for later placement:

```
private String[] enemies = {"Goblin", "Skeleton"};

private void buildEnemySelectionPanel()
{
    enemyPanel = new JPanel();
    enemyListPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    enemyListPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 85));
    enemyListPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    enemyPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(enemyPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    enemyList = new JList(enemies);

    enemyList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    enemyList.addListSelectionListener(new EnemyListListener());
    enemyListPanel.add(enemyList);
    enemyPanel.add(enemyListPanel);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Select Enemy"))
    {
        indexEnemy = enemyList.getSelectedIndex();
        indexEnemyWeapon = weaponList.getSelectedIndex();
      /* 
         here is where I'm having problems
       */
    }
}
```

So far I've tried to take all of the items from the `JList` and, matching them with the references from the original `String[] list` items that I sent to the `JList`, parsed the indexes and if they didn't match set to false.  Unfortunately as you are all probably well aware, compilation errors came up as result due to the fact that the `JList` is not *actually* a list.  Here is a sample of my `for` loop that I tried to use in my method above:

```
for(int x = 1; x < enemyList.length(); x++)
{
    if (!(enemies[x] == indexEnemy))
    {
        enemyList[x].setEnable(false);
    }
}
```

I've read the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ , (tried to link 'setEnable') among some examples but don't seem to be making the connection.

Ideally, what I wish to happen is that when the `ActionEvent` of my button is triggered, all non-selected options in my `JList` will be disabled.  I understand that the end-user will still be able to change his/her mind and make a different selection.  But I'd like to still receive some help on how I can set the non-selected items in my `JList` to `false` if they are not the `indexEnemy` from my method above.

Comment: What is jlist? What data are you storing in the JList? Do these values have a setEnabled method?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've added code to display the method containing the `JList enemyList`.  As for your question concerning `setEnabled` method, no.  I do not have such a method but would appreciate an example of how to implement a method of that type.

Comment: Well, clearly, `String` doesn't have a `setEnabled` method

Comment: @MadProgrammer I appreciate the helpful input but I would also appreciate a bit more information or help than just that?  If I knew how to approach this matter I would have known that!  hehe

Comment: `private String[] enemies = {"Goblin", "Skeleton"};` so the data in the `JList` are `String`s, the simply don't have a `setEnabled` method.  You need to define a different data type which can support your goals and maybe use a `ListCellRenderer` to support the states of the data type. Have a look at [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for more details